# User Account with Sub-Accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that has multiple users, very basic registration and login.   The Customer model has an ID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Address, and a few other properties.

There are many customers who are from the same Company, placing orders and the two Customers may not know that they have already placed the order for their company, because they are not connected in any way on the site.

I was thinking of creating some kind of administrative account for users from the same company.  The only secure way that I think this would work (because people can lie about their company), is to create a new Company model that will be registered to an administrator of the company, and then that administrator would be able to add new users associated only with that company.  So in other words we would have an CompanyA user, who can register and login, and then CompanyA can have CompanyA-UserA, CompanyA-UserB (they can pick their own usernames).

Question is: what is the best way to structure the schema for such a project and suggestions for best methods to go about this.

Comment: What is your question bro?

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but the usual answer for questions like I think you are asking is to have users belong to groups (and/or roles).  You authenticate by user, then get the users groups/roles and authorize not by user, but by role/group.  Look up _Roll based security_.  The other half of this is to make _Claims_ about your users and associate those claims with user operations - for example, the AddNewUser end-point in one of your controllers could have a claim that says "Only Admins can do this".  ASP.NET MVC provides a lot of this out of the box.

Comment: I think you're pointing me in the right direction, Flydog57.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am reading this wrong but I suggest making a Company object with its own ID

and bind that ID to the Customer object

and for the admin account situation -> I would abstract Customer to 'RegisteredUser' or something and extend for Admin/Customer/ect accounts

or just add a UserRole enum

(I come from Java background but I think this would work for all OOP)

Goodluck!

Comment: This is what I was thinking regarding the Company ID and Customer object. What do you mean by abstract Customer to Registered User? I know abstraction in C#, is that the same as in Java?

Comment: Should be basically you should create an interface(another class maybe) that has all of the same attributes that a typical customer would have

name/age/dob/user/pass/ect

Then you could create a class called Administrator that implements/extends that interface/class that has specific information for the admin 

and another one called Customer that has specific information for the customers 

You could also accomplish this with userroles